# How do I extract invoice number and invoice date from a PDF using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

How do I extract invoice number and invoice date from a PDF file using Excel VBA? I have all my code ready which searches for a specified pdf file (invoice pdf file) in a directory where a large number of invoices are stored. I only want to extract the invoice number and invoice date from that file, so this would only be a read-only operation. The invoice is system generated and therefore no handwritten text or values are there. I have searched dozens of solutions here but none of them is addressing my requirement.

I understand I do not need Acrobat Writer installed on my machine and Acrobat Reader's installation should suffice. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I have tried below code posted by another community member to first open the pdf file and extract its contents in a text string so that I could use instr function to extract the invoice number from that string by adding some additional lines of code but unfortunately, the code gets stuck at the line `If objAVDoc.Open(strFilename, "") Then` and gives a message that says

> "Activex Compnent cannot create object".

```
    Sub CallMyFunction()
    Dim myPDF As String
    myPDF = "C:\Users\syed\Desktop\invoice.pdf"
    getTextFromPDF (myPDF)


    End Sub


    Function getTextFromPDF(ByVal strFilename As String) As String
       Dim objAVDoc As New AcroAVDoc
       Dim objPDDoc As New AcroPDDoc
       Dim objPage As AcroPDPage
       Dim objSelection As AcroPDTextSelect
       Dim objHighlight As AcroHiliteList
       Dim pageNum As Long
       Dim strText As String
       Dim tCount As Long

       strText = ""
       If objAVDoc.Open(strFilename, "") Then
          Set objPDDoc = objAVDoc.GetPDDoc
          For pageNum = 0 To objPDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
             Set objPage = objPDDoc.AcquirePage(pageNum)
             Set objHighlight = New AcroHiliteList
             objHighlight.Add 0, 10000 ' Adjust this up if it's not getting all the text on the page
             Set objSelection = objPage.CreatePageHilite(objHighlight)

             If Not objSelection Is Nothing Then
                For tCount = 0 To objSelection.GetNumText - 1
                   strText = strText & objSelection.GetText(tCount)
                Next tCount
             End If
          Next pageNum
          objAVDoc.Close 1
       End If

       getTextFromPDF = strText

    End Function
```

Comment: You are going to run into other problems too... you define `getTextFromPDF` as a function that returns a string, but when you are calling it, you are not assigning it to a string... You are currently calling it like it's a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks for your comments braX. I will fix that but could you please advise how to get the other error fixed that refers to ActiveX component.

Comment: Which type library/reference did you add to get access to `AcroAVDoc`?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library and I am using Excel 2016

Comment: I have only the reader installed as you say you do and that library is not an option for me.

Comment: So it means that Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library does not support this, right? If so, do you have any other alternative? Let me know if you could think of any such thing. One option would be to create an instance of Word inside Excel VBA macro and then pull that invoice data from that instance of Word document.

Comment: I am not sure as I do not use Acrobat for developing, I'm just trying to help you get on the right track. I looked up some things on google and it looks like you would be on the right track. I suggest you do that as well until someone with more experience in this comes along.